# Offer (oneself) to do

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs

‎* The kids offered (themselves) to do the dishes.

(I wrote 'themselves' as object of the verb 'offer')

Can I think 'themselves' is omitted in the sentence?

Even if not omitted, it seems not to be different at all from the omitted sentence.

I just want to know whether it is grammatically correct, even though it looks unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically correct.

It is not the case that "themselves" is omitted. The word "offer" can have an infinitive verb as its object. Using two objects may be possible when offering someone else

> I offer my servant to do your dishes.

It is not natural to use "themselves" in a sentence "They offered themselves to do the dishes".